# Obtener el ultimo precio promedio mensual de cada producto

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero obtener de cada producto el  precio promedio del ultimo mes que se vendió cada producto. Se genera un problema en la segunda tabla temporal "precio_avg" debido a que cuando cambie el calculo de avg(punitdolar) as precio_ultimoUSD por el (sum(i.cantidad*i.punitdolar)/sum(i.cantidad)) as precio_ultimoUSD al ejecutar el query me sale

> "Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 64 Divide by zero error
>   encountered."

Intente solucionarlo con un cantidad > 0 para que no coja cantidades negativas o 0 pero el tema es que al hacer eso deja de reconocer ultima fecha y promedia todos los productos con el mismo codigo.

Solucion posible que en esta:

```
(sum(i.cantidad*i.punitdolar)/sum(i.cantidad)) as precio_ultimoUSD
```

vaya alguna especie de condicional que diga que si la cantidad que divide es cero ponga 0 y no error

```
with fecha_ultima as (select itemnumber,
    max(format(fecha, 'yyyyMM')) as Fecha_ultim from [gpper].[dbo].[peru_sales_report]
group by itemnumber)                                                        
--Vinculo de ultima fecha y precio promedio
,precio_avg as ( 
select u.itemnumber,
    u.fecha_ultim,
    (sum(i.cantidad*i.punitdolar)/sum(i.cantidad)) as precio_ultimoUSD
    --avg(punitdolar) as precio_ultimoUSD                                
from [gpper].[dbo].[peru_sales_report] i 
    left join fecha_ultima u  
    on i.itemnumber = u.itemnumber and format(i.fecha, 'yyyyMM') = u.fecha_ultim where i.cantidad <> 0
group by u.itemnumber, u.fecha_ultim) --Join con tabla precios
,precioabc as (
select a.*,
    b.precio_ultimoUSD from [dbo].[Precio_Inyeccion_soplado] a 
    left join precio_avg b
    on (a.id_producto = b.itemnumber)) --Join final con v_producción_altas
select a.*,
    a.peso_real_op/1000 as toneladas,
    c.virgen_rec,
    b.pesokilos as peso_unitario, 
    c.precio_teoricoUSD,
    f.precio_ultimoUSD,
    (costo_kardex/cantidad/3.24) as costo_unitarioUSD, 
    f.precio_ultimoUSD*a.cantidad as ingresoUSD,
    f.precio_ultimoUSD*a.cantidad-costo_kardex/3.24 as margenUSD from [GESTION].[prod].[v_produccion_altas] a 
    left join [gpper].[dbo].[Peru_Maestro_Articulos] b
    on (a.id_producto = b.Codigo)
    left join  [dbo].[Precio_Inyeccion_soplado] c
    on (a.id_producto = c.id_producto)
    left join  precioabc f
    on (a.id_producto = f.id_producto) where a.linea_negocio <> 'extrusion' and a.linea_negocio <> 'reventa'
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptualmente lo que te ocurre es una clásica división por 0:

```
select  100/sum(monto)
    from (select 0 as monto) T

Server: Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

Filtrar valores no nos sirve, por que al sumar, cualquier combinación podría dar 0. Lo que sí podemos hacer es usar una clausula `CASE WHEN .. ELSE .. END`, por ejemplo:

```
select  case when sum(monto)=0 then 0 else 100/sum(monto) end
    from (select 0 as monto) T
```

En tu caso sería algo así:

```
case when sum(i.cantidad) = 0 then 0 else sum(i.cantidad*i.punitdolar)/sum(i.cantidad) end
```

Answer (score 0):

La función COALESCE(,) devuelve un valor especifico cuando ocurre alguna excepción.

Ex.
COALESCE(100/0,0)
Devuelve 0.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).